# java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to ba.store.models.Merchants

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have a `listview` with `adapter` extending `BaseAdapter` in Fragment. On that `listview` I have implemented `scrollview` listener that detect when user reach the end of `listview`. In that case more data will load. Also I have a button on that fragment which on click will reset all filters and reload the list with starting items. Problem is when user is scrolling bottom and in same time (before new elements are loaded) press button app will crash with following error:

```
java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to ba.store.models.Merchants
```

This is the code where it's breaking apart:

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    Integer identity;
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    if (convertView == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sales_place_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        view = convertView;
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    }
    Merchants merchants = (Merchants) getItem(position);
    if (merchants != null) {
        identity = merchants.getMerchantId();
        viewHolder.merchant_name.setText(merchants.getMerchantName());
        viewHolder.merchant_category.setText(merchants.getCategoryName().toUpperCase());
        viewHolder.border_limit.setText(merchants.getBorderLimitAmount().toString() + " KM");
        viewHolder.end_loyalty.setText(merchants.getEndLoyaltyPoints().toString());
        viewHolder.begin_loyalty.setText(merchants.getStartLoyaltyPoints().toString());

        if (merchants.getImagePath().equals(""))
            Picasso.with(view.getContext()).load(R.drawable.placeholder_sales).fit().into(viewHolder.merchant_image);
        else
            Picasso.with(view.getContext()).load(merchants.getImagePath()).fit().into(viewHolder.merchant_image);

    }


    return view;

}
```

getItem method:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    if (merchants.size() > 0) {
        return merchants.get(position);
    } else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Please paste the implementation of the getItem() method

Comment: Why don't you disable the button till the time the data is loaded and appended to your list ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `getItem()` method.

If there if no data to display, the method will return false, a Boolean value. This breaks the cast in `getview()`.

Change the `getItem()` method to this:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    if (merchants.size() > 0)
        return merchants.get(position);
    else
        return null;
}
```

And in `getView()`, replace:

```
 Merchants merchants = (Merchants) getItem(position);
    if (merchants != null) {
        identity = merchants.getMerchantId();
        ...
```

with:

```
if (getItem(position) != null) {
    Merchants merchants = (Merchants) getItem(position);
    identity = merchants.getMerchantId();
    ...
```

This will fix the crash, but you also have to check why `merchants.getSize()` is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `getItem()` as follows

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    if (merchants.size() > 0) {
        return merchants.get(position);
    } else
        return null;
}
```

as you are returning `false` in your method when it's of size is zero, It's creating casting error saying `false` can't be converted to `Merchants`

Comment: This will interfere with the logic. Adapters should just display the data set contents, not edit it in any way.